# How can you identify how many solutions systems have in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

How to determine    how many    solutions   does each   of  the 
following   systems have in $\mathbb{R}^3$? (Infinitely many    solutions/Unique    solutions/No    Solutions)

a) $\begin{cases}f + g + h = 13\\
f – h = −2\end{cases}$

b) $\begin{cases}3x + 4y – z = 8\\
5x – 2y + z = 4\\
2x – 2y + z = 1\end{cases}$

c) $\begin{cases}S –   T  –  W = 8\\
    5S + 2T + 4W = 0\\ 
   –3S + 3T + 3W =20\end{cases}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (c), adding three times the first equation to the third equation yields $0=44$, which is clearly impossible, so there are no solutions.

For (b), subtracting the third equation from the second yields $3x=3$ or $x=1$; thus $3+4y-z=8$ and $5-2y+z=4$; adding those yields $8+2y=12$ or $y=2$ and thus $z=3$, so $(x,y,z)=(1,2,3)$ is the unique solution.

For (a), adding and subtracting the equations we get $2f+g=11$ and $h=f+2$; $f$ could be anything, and then $g$ and $h$ are determined, so there are infinitely many solutions.

Comment: or $S-T-W=8$ and $S-T-W=\frac{-20}3$

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear explanation! Could you also explain how I can identify how many solutions systems a and b have?

Comment: @Vera:  I edited my answer to include a and b

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's all clear now :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the determinant to evaluate whether the system has unique solutions.

- $ det A \neq 0 \iff \text{unique solution}$
- $ det A = 0 \implies \text{infinite number of solutions or none}$

The simplest way to determine between infinite or none is to solve and see if the system is inconsistent (results in contradictory constraints).

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/249919/for-deta-0-how-do-we-know-if-a-has-no-solution-or-infinitely-many-soluti) answer may be helpful too.