# How can a system $AX=B$ have a solution in $\mathbb{F}_{p}$, when $\det(A) \equiv 0\pmod p$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, finite-fields

Let the system $AX=B$, where $$A=\begin{bmatrix}8&3\\2&6\end{bmatrix} \ \text{and} \ B=\begin{bmatrix}3\\-1\end{bmatrix}.$$

The book says it does not have a solution in $\mathbb{F}_{2}$ and $\mathbb{F}_{3}$ but have a solution in $\mathbb{F}_{7}$, even though $\det A≡ 0 \pmod{7}$. Can someone please explain how it's possible?

Comment: $$\pmatrix{1&1\\1&1}\pmatrix{x\\y}=\pmatrix{1\\1}$$ has a real solution, even though the matrix is singular.

Comment: Singular matrix can have solutions.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Non-zero determinant means there's a unique solution

Comment: Then why not in F2 and F3?

Comment: Cf. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/249919/for-deta-0-how-do-we-know-if-a-has-no-solution-or-infinitely-many-soluti)

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. I figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

As in all fields, a linear system $AX=B$, where $A$ is a square matrix, has solutions in the field $F$ if and only if the rank of $A$ is equal to the rank of the augmented matrix $[A | B\,]$. Here is how the augmented matrix can be rewritten in each field:
$$\begin{matrix}
\mathbf F_2 & \mathbf F_3 & \mathbf F_7 \\
\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}
\mkern-4mu 0&1& 1\mkern-6mu\\\mkern-4mu 0&0&1\mkern-4mu 
\end{array}\right]
&\quad \left[\begin{array}{cc|c}
\mkern-4mu 2 & 0 & 0\mkern-6mu\\\mkern-4mu 2&0& 2\mkern-4mu 
\end{array}\right]\quad
& \left[\begin{array}{cc|c}
\mkern-4mu 1 & 3 & 3\mkern-6mu\\\mkern-4mu 2&6&6\mkern-4mu 
\end{array}\right]
\end{matrix}$$